# Always show "Basic Completion" list while typing in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

When I type in `httpre`, PyCharm gives me the list:
[image]

But if I use "Basic Completion", it shows me:
[image]

Which I think is much better because when I am coding I always check what objects and members I might be able to use without finding documents elsewhere.

Is it possible?